# converting anchor hrefs to unique tags using regex and javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this sample data:

```
<products_database>
<product>
         <id>##1234
         <a name ="toy">toy</a>
         <weight>5kg
         <a href ="#block">block</a>
</product>
<product>
          <id>##56789
          <a name ="brick">brick</a>
          <a name ="lego">lego</a>
          <a name ="block">block</a>
          <weight>2kg
          <a href ="#toy">toy</a>
</product>
<product>
          <id>##1357902
          <a href ="#toy">toy</a>
          <a href ="#brick">brick</a>
          <weight>4kg
</product>
</product_database>
```

I'd like to convert the hrefs into:

```
<products_database>
<product>
         <id>##1234
         <a name ="toy">toy</a>
         <weight>5kg
         <..pd ##56789 #block>block</a>
</product>
<product>
          <id>##56789
          <a name ="brick">brick</a>
          <a name ="lego">lego</a>
          <a name ="block">block</a>
          <weight>2kg
          <..pd ##1234 #toy>toy</a>
</product>
<product>
          <id>##1357902
          <..pd ##1234 #toy>toy</a>
          <..pd ##56789 #brick>brick</a>
          <weight>4kg
</product>
```

the href is to be converted into this unique tag in which it gets the "id" in each individual "product" where their "a href" values are equivalent to their "a name". I'm only allowed to use javascript and regular expression any help would be appreciated.

Comment: yeah, I'm pretty sure about my expected output. so far i wanted to try putting the a name and id's into a hash but I'm not familiar with the syntax.

Comment: Have you written any code so far? If you could give us that we could help suggest ways of developing it further.

Comment: two people helped you more than two days ago, but no thanks or any other comment :(

Answer (score 1):

I tried to figure out what exactly you need things to do, and wrote a solution that might do what you need it to.

```js
//var findProduct = /<product>\s+<id>(##\d+)\s+((?:<a name ="[^"]+">[^<]+<\/a>)+)\s+<weight>(\d+kg)\s+((?:<a href ="#[^"]+">[^<]+<\/a>)+)\s+<\/product>/g;

var byName = {}, products = [];

var findProduct = /<product>\s+([\W\w]+?)\s+<\/product>/g;
var findTag = /<([\w]+)(?: (name|href) ="#?([^"]+)")?>([^<\n\r]+)/g;

var data = document.getElementById("data").value;
data.replace(findProduct, function(match, tags) {
  var product = {
    id: "", names: [], weight: "", links: []
  };
  tags.replace(findTag, function(match, tagName, attr, attrValue, tagValue) {
    switch (tagName) {
      case "id": product.id = tagValue; break;
      case "weight": product.weight = tagValue; break;
      case "a":
        if (attr === "name") { product.names.push(attrValue); byName[attrValue] = product; }
        else /* if (attr === "href") */ { product.links.push(attrValue); }
        break;
    }
  });
  products.push(product);
});

data = "<product_database>" + products.map(function(product) {
  return "<product><id>" + product.id + "\n<weight>" + product.weight + "\n" +
    product.names.map(function(name) {
      return "<a name =\"" + name + "\">" + name + "</a>";
    }).join("\n") +
    product.links.map(function(link) {
      return "<..pd " + byName[link].id + " #" + link + ">block</a>";
    }).join("\n")
  + "\n</product>";
}).join("\n") + "</product_database>";

document.getElementById("data").value = data;
```

```html
  <textarea id="data" cols=50 rows=30><products_database>
<product>
         <id>##1234
         <a name ="toy">toy</a>
         <weight>5kg
         <a href ="#block">block</a>
</product>
<product>
          <id>##56789
          <a name ="brick">brick</a>
          <a name ="lego">lego</a>
          <a name ="block">block</a>
          <weight>2kg
          <a href ="#toy">toy</a>
</product>
<product>
          <id>##1357902
          <a href ="#toy">toy</a>
          <a href ="#brick">brick</a>
          <weight>4kg
</product>
</product_database></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use this (mainly regex approach), but I am not sure how error-resistant this is:

```
var a = '<products_database>\n<product>\n         <id>##1234\n         <a name ="toy">toy</a>\n         <weight>5kg\n         <a href ="#block">block</a>\n</product>\n<product>\n          <id>##56789\n          <a name ="brick">brick</a>\n          <a name ="lego">lego</a>\n          <a name ="block">block</a>\n          <weight>2kg\n          <a href ="#toy">toy</a>\n</product>\n<product>\n          <id>##1357902\n          <a href ="#toy">toy</a>\n          <a href ="#brick">brick</a>\n          <weight>4kg\n</product>\n</product_database>';

while (a.match(/(?:<id>(##\d+)((?:[\s\S](?!<id))*?<a name =")(.+?)("[\S\s]*?)<a href ="#\3">|<a href ="#(.+?)">([\S\s]*?)<id>(##\d+)((?:[\s\S](?!<id))*?<a name =")\1")/g) != null) {
  a = a.replace(/<id>(##\d+)((?:[\s\S](?!<id))*?<a name =")(.+?)("[\S\s]*?)<a href ="#\3">/g, '<id>$1$2$3$4<.. pd $1 #$3>').replace(/<a href ="#(.+?)">([\S\s]*?)<id>(##\d+)((?:[\s\S](?!<id))*?<a name =")\1"/gm, '<.. pd $3 #$1>$2<id>$3$4$1"');
}

a;
```

There are two regexs

1.) matching if the id comes before the href

2.) matching if the id comes after the href

You have to loop through it, because regex would not match the id multiple times.

Please ask if something is not clear.